# Why is my binary search implementation returning -1?

Tags: dart

This is my `main.dart`:

```
import 'edgecases.dart';
main () {
  var card = edgecases(0)['input']['cards'];
  var query = edgecases(0)['input']['query'];
  var result = locate_card(edgecases(0)['input']['cards'], edgecases(0)['input']['query']);
  var output = edgecases(0)['output'];
  print("Cards:- $card");
  print("Query:- $query");
  print("Output:- $result");
  print("Actual answer:- $output");
}
```

And this is my `edgecases.dart`:

```
edgecases ([edgecasenumber = null]) { //You may make it required, I provided a null as default to check if my syntax is going right.
  List tests = [];                    
  var edge1 = {'input': {
        'cards': [13, 11, 10, 7, 4, 3, 1, 0],
        'query': 1
    }, 'output': 6};
  tests.addAll([edge1]);
  if (edgecasenumber == null){  // This if is useless here so you may 
    return 'Null type object coud not be found.';
  } else {
     return tests.elementAt(edgecasenumber); // Indexing in dart also starts with 0.
  }
}

locate_card (List cards, int query){
  int lo = 0;
  int hi = cards.length - 1;
  print('$lo  $hi');
  while (lo <= hi) {
    //print('hello'); Uncomment to see if it is entering the loop
    var mid = (lo + hi) ~/ 2;
    var mid_number = cards[mid];

    print("lo:$lo ,hi:$hi, mid:$mid, mid_number:$mid_number");

    if (mid_number == query){
      return mid;
    } else if (mid_number < query) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (mid_number > query) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    };
  return -1; //taking about this line

  };
}
```

[I have cut short the code here so you may find some things as unnecessary so just ignore it XD]

Actually I am trying to implement binary search here(I have previously successfully implemented it in python, I am implementing in dart to learn the language.)

On testing it with first edge case(that is on running the command `dart main.dart`), I found that it is returning the value -1 which was wrong, so I  tried commenting the `return -1;` line in `edgecases.dart` file to see what happens as it was made to handle another edge case(edgecase if the list is empty, here I have removed that for simplicity). I am not able to understand why it is returning -1 if it gives the right value on commenting that line. Any possible explainations and solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also I am returning -1 here because I have considered it a convention to return if the query is not found in the cards(list).

Comment: The `return -1` prematurely exits the loop whenever the middle value is not equal to the query.  You instead need to return -1 when you've run out of elements to search.  It should be outside of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it right. Just place the `return -1;` after the `while` loop's closing brace at the very end of `locate_card`.

Comment: Thanks @Ber ,It worked :). Just one more thing, Even if I had written it in the braces of while, yet I provided the same indentation to `return` and `while` but dart didn't threw any error. Does that mean indentation doesn't really matter in dart programming?

Comment: Whitespace ist not significant in Dart. So indentation is ignored by the compiler. You should configure your IDE to run Dartfmt (the Dart formatter) every time you save your code.